# Arguments of variable number of integers in method in java

Tags: java, methods, integer, arguments, variadic-functions

*Question:* Write a method that takes as input a variable number of integers. The method  should return the average of the integers as a double. Write a full program to test the   method.

That code below creates an array of 10 integers and finds their average. However, I need it to create a variable number of arguments (int...a) where any number of integers entered can be averaged. Can someone help me.Thanks.

My code:

```
package average.pkgint;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class AverageInt {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int [] number = new int [10];
        Scanner b = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter your 10 numbers:");
        for (int i = 0; i < number.length; i++) {
             number[i] =  b.nextInt() ;

        }

        System.out.println("The average is:"+Avnt(number));

    }

    public static int  Avnt(int [] a){//declare arrays of ints
        int result = 1;      
        int sum = 0;
        //iterate through array
        for (int num : a) {
              sum += num; 
        }
            double average = ( sum / a.length);//calculate average of elements in array
            result = (int)average;

             return result;

    }

    }
```

Comment: Don't use `int` as type of `sum`. You can make that overflow with just 2 ints (`Integer.MAX_VALUE + 1 == Integer.MIN_VALUE`). Use long or double instead.

Answer (score 1):

This is a way of getting as many variables as you want to a method and going through them all:

```
public static void testVarArgs(int... numbers){
    for(double u: numbers) {
        System.out.println(u);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just change your method declaration to a variable length parameter:

```
public static int  Avnt(int ... a){//declare variable int arguments
```

When you use a variable length parameter, you supply the values in the method invocation. For example,

```
    System.out.println(Avnt(1,2,3));
    System.out.println(Avnt(1,2,3,4,5,6,9,9,9,10,10));
```

Actually, this looks like it meets your requirements. Just add method calls in your main() similar to these.

Comment: How would I re-write this program then. Do I still need to loop through the array in main. Also, since it would now be a variable number of arguments do I still need to set the array size.

Comment: Leave your method as is. "a" will become an array inside your method. All you need to do is change the declaration as above.

Comment: Thanks..but the number of integers I can average is still limited to 10 since that's the size of my array in main. How do I make it unlimited?

Comment: See the System.out.println() statements above.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to read the number of integers as the first input you can declare a `stack` in stead of an `array`

```
Stack<Integer> numbers=new Stack<>()
```

and then you can add the numbers with the `add` method.

Comment: Thanks for the heads-up. I was working at something with an array of stacks and forgot to change the left part.

Comment: it does but the question said " Write a method that takes as input a VARIABLE number of integers". the program takes only 10. want to rewrite using the (int...a) syntax.

Comment: You just add them as a stack and when you call the `int...a` method you make a conversion from `stack` to `array`.